# elasticsearch and kibana setup on different machines

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to know what is the best setup to have an elasticsearch data node and kibana server on separate machines. I have setup multiple elasticsearch data nodes and would like to show all dashboards on one server but not sure how to do that. I do not want to have different urls to view different dashboards. I set up the data nodes with logstash shipper on each machine so all I need now is to have kibana get data from each different data node. Is that possible? 
I edited the config file for kibana as follows:

elasticsearch: "http://"192.168.xx.xxx":9200"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far Kibana 3 do not support what you need. You can refer to [this](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/214).

As the webpage say, maybe you want to set an proxy or a redirect page.

Comment: thank you for responding. So one more question: is it necessary to install kibana as well or does elasticsearch not contain kibana integrated into it as well.

Comment: Kibana and elasticsearch arr two diffirent software. You need to download both from elasticsearch website